# FFmpeg `Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream`

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-conversion

Consider a simple FFmpeg conversion, such as:

```
ffmpeg -i dream.wav dream-ffmpeg.mp3 -y
```

It produces the following warning:

> **Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono**

How can I tell FFmpeg, via command-line arguments, that the input stream will always be mono?

By goal is to be more specific, to avoid unnecessary warnings and keep my code clean. (So I may spot actual issues.)

(I am not trying to [get rid of all warnings altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303166/silencing-guessed-channel-layout-for-ffmpeg).)

My understand form the [FFmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) was that `-ac 1` would do the trick, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i dream.wav -ac 1 dream-ffmpeg.mp3 -y
```

But the warning's still here.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303554/8013879 `You can [...] disable performing the action of guessing (not just its announcement) by the input option of -guess_layout_max [...]. The issue with this is that the output won't be flagged with a channel layout. You can correct this by explicitly setting output channels option -ac N where N is the number of channels in the output.`

Comment: For future reference please always show the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually seen the answer but somehow failed to use the argument it seems…

In any case `-guess_layout_max 0` will do the trick. e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -i dream.wav dream-ffmpeg.mp3 -y
```