# Unable to extract audio with ffmpeg for youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I'm struggling to get youtube to accept an audio of a conference we have recorded. Youtube seems to ignore the audio of the recordings, which I can hear with VLC or Video (the Gnome player). 
So my idea is to use the powerful ffmpeg to do some conversion of the video and the upload a working version on youtube.

This is the description of the file I get from ffmpeg

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'BVAN.mp4':                                                                                                                                                                          
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: iso4avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2018-07-15T08:49:37.000000Z
  Duration: 00:22:44.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26200 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, 22836 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-15T08:49:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H264/AVC
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24be (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-15T08:49:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-15T08:49:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
```

I tried: 
 - [FFmpeg `Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream`](https://superuser.com/questions/1252183/ffmpeg-guessed-channel-layout-for-input-stream)
 - https://askubuntu.com/questions/706584/vlc-does-not-play-pcm-s24-le-audio-in-mov-file
 - [FFmpeg command to convert MP3 to AAC](https://superuser.com/questions/370625/ffmpeg-command-to-convert-mp3-to-aac)
and many other questions, but without success. 
And more concretely, none of these commands works.

```
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:audio aac -b:audio 128k -codec:video libx264 -crf 23  disagio.mp4
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k out.mp4
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:video libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:video 0 -codec:audio libopus -vbr on -threads 10 lungo.webm
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:video libvpx-vp9 -crf 16 -b:video 0 -codec:audio libopus -vbr on -threads 10 lungo.webm
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:video libvpx-vp9 -crf 50 -b:video 0 -codec:audio libopus -vbr on -threads 10 lungo.avi
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:video libvpx-vp9 -crf 50 -b:video 0 -codec:audio libopus -vbr on -threads 10 -c:a aac lungo.avi
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4  -c:a flac -c:v copy merda.avi
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -codec:audio aac -b:audio 128k -codec:video libx264 -crf 23  disagio.mp4
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:a:0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -guess_layout_max 0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:a:0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -i BVA.mp4   -ac 1 -c copy -map 0:a:0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -i BVA.mp4   -ac 1 -c copy -map 0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg-i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:1 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:1 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 maybebaby.mp4 
ffmpeg -i BVA.mp4 -c copy -map 0:2  maybebaby.mp4
```

Comment: See the guidelines: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4603579?hl=en

Comment: Take the first command you tried. What happens when you play the result locally? And what happens on YT?

Comment: All of the commands does not extract the audio correctly, as the resulting file has a kind of white noise in the background even locally.